# invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value="[object Object]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.0.5

Tags: web3js

I am getting error on login page  **Unable to register this account: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value="[object Object]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.0.5)** while trying to send user name and uint to the contract

i stuck here from last 15 hours but i cant find where the problem is so can you please anyone help me to find this

This is my code where i am facing error

```
let userContractObj;
let _gCurrentWallet = "";
let data;
fetch('/Users.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsondata => {
        data = jsondata;
    });
const providerUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:7545"; 
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerUrl));
function changeWalletAddress(accounts) {
    $("#wallet").val(accounts);
    _gCurrentWallet = accounts;
}
async function loadContractForThisPage() {
    $("#progress-div").hide();
    // Check if Ethereum provider is available
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
        try {
            // Request account access if needed
            await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
            // Use the first account returned by MetaMask
            const defaultAccount = accounts[0];
            if (defaultAccount) {
                changeWalletAddress(defaultAccount);
                userContractObj = new web3.eth.Contract(data.abi, '0x8b951d11F06D850705299CDc0dF75e5D4d048470');
                console.log("userContractObj", userContractObj)
                // Example: check if user needs to register after contract is loaded
                if ($("#fullname").val().length > 1) {
                    await submitNewUser(userContractObj, $("#role").val(), $("#fullname").val(), defaultAccount);
                }
            } else {
                console.error("No accounts found.");
                alert("No accounts found. Please make sure MetaMask is unlocked and an account is connected.");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
            alert("An error occurred. Please check the console for details.");
        }
    } else {
        console.error("Ethereum provider not detected.");
        alert("Ethereum provider not detected. Please make sure you have MetaMask installed.");
    }
}
async function submitNewUser(userRole, username) {
    const userWallet = $("#wallet").val();
    $("#progress-div").show();
    $("#form_buttons").hide();
    try {
        userContractObj = new web3.eth.Contract(data.abi, '0x8b951d11F06D850705299CDc0dF75e5D4d048470');
        // console.log(userContractObj)
        console.log("functions", userContractObj.methods)
        await userContractObj.methods.registerUser(userRole, username)
            .send({ from: userWallet }), (err, result) => {
                if (result) {
                    $("#progress-div").hide();
                    $("#form_buttons").show();
                    console.log("CALL-SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                    console.log("CALL-ACHIEVE: User registered successfully");
                    alert("Account is successfully registered");
                    showFullNameInputField(username, userRole, false);
                }
            }
    } catch (error) {
        $("#progress-div").hide();
        $("#form_buttons").show();
        alert("Unable to register this account: " + error.message);
    }
}
async function onSubmitForm() {
    
    if ($("#fullname").val().length > 1) {
        loadContractForThisPage(); 
        if (userContractObj) { 
            submitNewUser($("#role").val(), $("#fullname").val());
        } else {
            alert("Contract is still loading. Please try again later.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Make sure to enter full user name");
    }
}
```